# MetaClasses to remove duplication of class definitions

Tags: python, class, refactoring, composition, metaclass

I have a few classes defined as below in Python:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Group:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.items = {}

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.items[name]

    def __setitem__(self, name, item):
        self.items[name] = item

class Section:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.groups = {}

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.groups[name]

    def __setitem__(self, name, group):
        self.groups[name] = group

class List:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.sections = {}

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.sections[name]

    def __setitem__(self, name, section):
        self.sections[name] = section
```

The pattern of `Group`, `Section`  and `List` is similar. Is there a way in Python using MetaClasses to refactor this to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - I'd do it using inheritance as well, but instead of having the specific attribute name defined in `__init__`, would set it as a class attribute.  The base could even be declared as abstract.

```py
class GroupBase():
    collection_name = "items"
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        setattr(self.collection_name, {})

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, self.collection_name)[name]


    def __setitem__(self, name, item):
        getattr(self, self.collection_name)[name] = item
    
class Section(GroupBase):
    collection_name = "groups"

class List(GroupBase):
    collection_name = "sections"
```

Note that more class attributes could be used at runtime, for example
to specify the item type for each collection, and enforce typing inside `__setitem__`, if needed.

Or, as you asked, it **is possible** to literally use a string-template system and just use an "exec" statement inside a metaclass to create new classes.
That would be closer to what "templates" are. The class code itself would live inside a string, and the patterns can use normal strign substitution with `.format()`. The major difference with C++ templates is that the language runtime itself will do the substitution at runtime - instead of compile (to bytecode) time. The `exec` function actually causes the text templat to be compiled at this point - yes, it is slower than pre-compiled code, but since it is run just once, at import time, that does not make a difference:

```py
group_class_template = """\
class {name}:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.{collection_name} = {{}}

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.{collection_name}[name]

    def __setitem__(self, name, item):
        self.{collection_name}[name] = item
"""

class TemplateMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, cls_namespace, template):
        # It would be possible to run the template with the module namespace
        # where the stub is defined, so that expressions
        # in the variables can access the namespace there
        # just set the global dictionary where the template
        # will be exec-ed to be the same as the stub's globals:
        # modulespace = sys._getframe().f_back.f_globals

        # Othrwise, keeping it simple, just use an empty dict:
        modulespace = {}

        cls_namespace["name"] = name

        exec(template.format(**cls_namespace), modulespace)
        # The class is execed actually with no custom metaclass - type is used.
        # just return the created class. It will be added to the modulenamespace,
        # but special attributes like "__qualname__" and "__file__" won't be set correctly.
        # they can be set here with plain assignemnts, if it matters that they are correct.
        return modulespace[name]


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Group(metaclass=TemplateMeta, template=group_class_template):
    collection_name = "items"


class Section(metaclass=TemplateMeta, template=group_class_template):
    collection_name = "groups"
    

class List(metaclass=TemplateMeta, template=group_class_template):
    collection_name = "sections"
```

And pasting this in the REPL I can just use the created classes:

```py
In [66]: a = Group("bla")

In [67]: a.items
Out[67]: {}

In [68]: a["x"] = 23

In [69]: a["x"]
Out[69]: 23


In [70]: a.items
Out[70]: {'x': 23}
```

The major drawback of doing it this way is that the template itself is seem just as a string, and the tooling like linters, static type checkers, auto-complete based in static scannng in IDEs, won't work for the templated classes. The idea could be evolved so that templates would be valid Python code, in ".py" files - they can be read as any other file at import time - one'd just need to specify a templating system other than using the built-in `str.format` so that templates could be valid code. For example, if one defines that names prefixed and ending with a single underscore are names that will be substituted in the template, regular expressions could be used for the name-replacement insteaf of `.format`.

Comment: Cool answer, I like your solution more than mine, having the name as class attribute is indeed smarter. Also interesting your metaclass example with the string template. You should get the accepted answer points :)

Comment: Thank you dzang! The accepte answer decision is up to the O.P. - I think the template part is indeed what he was trying to do, even if not the best approach. And I still have a feeling that there might be a better way them the 3 approaches we have so far.

Answer (score 2):

You could use inheritance:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Group(Item):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self._dict = {}
        self.items = self._dict

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._dict[name]

    def __setitem__(self, name, item):
        self._dict[name] = item

class Section(Group):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.groups = self._dict


class List(Group):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.sections = self._dict
```

Comment: Good point. Inheritence would to do the job in this case. I used templates in C++ for this pattern and I was wondering if there's an elegant MetaClass solution in Python without resorting to inheritance..

Answer (score 1):

Another option that is more similar to a templating method could be to use `type` to dynamically generate your objects:

```
def factory(cls_name, collection_name='_data'):
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return eval(f'self.{collection_name}[key]')

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        exec(f'self.{collection_name}[key] = value')
    
    attrs = {
        '__setitem__': __setitem__,
        '__getitem__': __getitem__,
        '__init__': __init__,
        collection_name: {}
    }
    
    exec(f'{cls_name} = type(cls_name, (), attrs)')
    
    return eval(cls_name)


Item = factory('Item')
Group = factory('Group', 'items')
Section = factory('Section', 'groups')
List = factory('List', 'sections')

g = Group('groupA')
s = Section('section_one')
l = List('list_alpha')

g[1] = 10
s['g'] = g

print(g.items, s.groups, l.sections)
```

> {1: 10} {'g': <**main**.Group object at 0x7fd87bdfecd0>} {}

Comment: You could use getattr and setattr instead of the exec/eval patterns. Despite having their uses, exec/eval are not an elegant practice, and are an order of magnitude slower than "in Python" counterparts. This slowdown does not matter much if done once at import time, but this code would run it on each method invocation.

Comment: indeed, good point, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't like using exec/eval either, much better the way you suggest!